# Change URL in WebView instead of open browser

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

When I click a link inside my WebView, Android open browser instead of changing URL in WebView.

Here's my fragment where WebView is (R.layout.webview contain WebView only):

```
package com.example.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class EuDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    private WebView viewer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        viewer = (WebView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview, container, false);

        return viewer;
    }

    public void updateUrl(String newUrl) {
        Log.d("EuDetailsFragment", "Updating url...");
        WebView detailsView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailsView);
        detailsView.loadUrl(newUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? It's hard to tell what you are wanting from the way your question is currently worded.

Comment: I had wrong title, sorry. I want change URL in WebView instead of open browser

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default behavior is that when you click a link it will ask the ActivityManager to find an appropriate app to handle the link. You may override this behavior(which will force the current WebView to load the new url in itself instead) like this:

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Even shorter version `myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); `  -from the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(intent);
```